# Restoring overwritten .RData file

Tags: r, workspace, rdata

So today when starting up, before having my coffee, I accidentally wrote `save.image` instead of `load` when trying to load my workspace and now my workspace fill is overwritten by an empty file and I unfortunately have no recent back-up. Rerunning all my code would take several hours, thus I am asking you, is there a way to restore my previous file? Or is running the code necessary? Thank you in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: If your workspace file is overwritten by an empty file, then the data is still somewhere on disk. Maybe a file recovery utility can retrieve it? Anyway this is a OS question, not an R one.

Comment: R doesn't save a backup as far as I know. If you use Dropbox or a similar service and the image was synced, you can revert to a previous version. Generally speaking, working with RData files is bad practice for this exact reason. Try to write shorter scripts and save intermediate files for objects which took a long time to produce with `saveRDS()`-